# How to downgrade LG L90 D410 from Lollipop 5.0.2 to KitKat 4.4.2?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lg

I have LG L90 D410 smartphone. It had KitKat 4.4.2 OS when I purchased it. It was working pretty fine. After a couple of months I upgraded it to Lollipop 5.0.2. But after using this latest Android version, I realized that my phone went too slower. Along with this hanging, my phone started encountering various other issues too. On top of that I didn't like this latest android version too. Then i started searching how we can downgrade from Lollipop to Kitkat but I didn't find any relevant resource for my phone. Though I saw some tutorials regarding LG G2, G3 etc. but main problem was that I couldn't fine any appropriate stock firmware of KitKat 4.4.2 for my phone. I searched a lot and though I downloaded a couple of stock firmwares of Kitkat but when I started downgrading my phone with the help of LG flash tool, the process couldn't completed; even it didn't start at all. Also i saw the language list was empty in the LG flash tool when i selected a different country other than korea. So please tell me first where can i download original official KitKat 4.4.2 for my phone that was pre-installed when i bought this phone and secondly how can I downgrade it back to KitKat? I will be really very thankful to all who would help me to solve this serious problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LG Source](http://opensource.lge.com/osSch/list?types=NAME&search=d410) page has your stock images plus the kernels too. Just scroll down the top section to D410, there are 3 different ones: D410, D410H, & D410HN (pick the proper one for your device).

There are many references to downgrading the D410, but those were inconcise/misleading/incoherent. Only relevant one I found was on XDA [for downgrading](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-l90/general/guide-flash-stock-kdz-offline-lg-l90-t2803479).

For [rooting and tools](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2770938), I recommend to use this reference.

*There were a few variables that would have made this answer too lengthy to post here, so links were used instead.*

**Please fully read all links before using any of the steps mentioned there within**

---

***remember***

***1. Perform a backup***

***2. Downgrading android will ERASE/WIPE/DELETE everything***

***3. YOU assume all responsibility for using any of the steps mentioned in the links***

---

**all links have been fixed and verified**

Comment: I don't think you had checked the URLs before giving them. All were gone to 404 Page Not Found except http://forum.xda-developers.com. Can you please provide me working links?

Comment: I have resolved your URLs problems. Actually you had given bad http that went to 404. It's OK now. Thanks.

Comment: I downloaded my d410 zip folder. While downloading I thought, it had kdz file but when i extracted it, then it came out to be a very large folder having a lot files. Now i don't understand what to do? Where is the required kitkat .kdz file for flashing?

Comment: Links fixed and verified, I am sorry for the inconvenience. The version for 4.4.2 should be v10a, you will need the kernel also. (The v10d should be for 4.4.4)

Comment: oh but there is not .kdz file to use in lg flash tool. plz guide me.

Comment: as i already told u there is a bulk of files in the folder after download, i don't know what to do next? Where is kdz?

Comment: The kdz is an archive with all the files that you see in that folder. Please re-read the links (plus all the comments), the information is stated right in the links. I don't have the D410, so I can't try this method out. Are you following their instructions to the letter (exactly)?

Comment: Do these instructions work with the LG G Vista, or is it specific to the phone mentioned? I'd like to downgrade to kitkat but can't find anything relating to the LG Vista. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Audrey I don't an LG Vista to try it on. So the steps might be similar. But I don't know.